# NSCollectionView or NSTableView automatic height adjustment of cells

Tags: macos, nstableview, appkit, nscollectionview

In iOS you could use:

`self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

to achieve automatic height adjustment of cells.

Is there any way to achieve this behaviour in macOS with `NSCollectionView` or `NSTableView`?

Answer (score 3):

Talking about NSTableView... As of El Capitan there was no easy way to do this. Not sure about new Sierra SDK.

From my experience, the most reliable way to regulate table row's height is to use NSTableViewDelegate method:

```
 func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat {

    //Here you do some magic measuring actual content of the cell and returning heigh
}
```

The only positive thing is that some controls have: `fittingSize` property and can simplify process.

Also, dynamic content change will require you to call `noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged` method of table view, to cause that delegate method be called again where your code will recalculate new height.

Answer (score 0):

With **macOS 11** and newer, the situation is as follows:

`NSTableView` can now actually use auto layout to achieve automatic height adjustment of cells. You must properly configure your cell template(s) to use auto layout, and you must instruct the table to use auto layout (can also be done in the storyboard) for row height calculations:

```
tableView.usesAutomaticRowHeights = true
```

`NSCollectionView` is currently (2021) still behind in features compared to the iOS counterpart, and still doesn't support any tableview feature like automatic row heights.